# CATiled Layer Question~

Tags: xcode, uiwebview, catiledlayer

Was wondering how to apply the CATiled Layer to a webView rather than a scrollView. Went through a lot of books as well as searches and found absolutely nothing regarding how to successfully apply a CATiled Layer to a webView. The basic functionality is to make the website rendering smoother on a webView. I'd really appreciate if someone could provide their insight regarding this.

Thanks,
-Zee-

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. UIWebView is essentially just a wrapper for webkit which uses it's own techniques for tiling. Apple does not want you to go messing with that.